# Pivot data into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, memory, pivot, pivot-table

I am trying to pivot data using the pivot_table function for dataframes

My original dataframe df has shape ***(630352,5)*** and the resulting pivoted dataset should be ***(395194,196784)*** however the error message I am getting is this:

```
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py", line 177, in _make_selectors
    mask.put(selector, True)

IndexError: index 458495173 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 458444768
```

This is the code im using to pivot the data.

```
df_pivot= df.pivot_table(index=['saleorder'],columns='product', values='quantity',aggfunc=sum)
```

The original df is of this format

```
saleorder | product | desc | id | quantity

12345     | bs1234  | abc  | 2  | 1
12345     | bs12214 | abc  | 2  | 1
12312     | bs12214 | abc  | 2  | 1
```

Comment: Can you share sample of your data frame?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski please see original post, added a sample format

Comment: No idea. Maybe you'd split the df into two, and test them separately with "pivot_table". df= df.sort_values('saleorder'), Look for an index that  is a start of a new 'saleorder', eg.: 300000 . df1=df.iloc[:300000], df2=df.iloc[300000:]

Comment: @kantal thats what I have currently done but once I have pivoted each chunk, how would I merge them back together. I cant just use an outer merge because its possible product IDs will be repeated in which case I would want them as a new row in the merged dataframe and not a duplicated column.

Comment: @Isra Concatenate them!  If the pivoted data frames are df1p and df2p:  dfrslt= pd.concat([df1p,df2p],sort=False)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment:

```
    # Test data:
    text="""saleorder | product | desc | id | quantity 

     10001     | prod01 | abc  | 2  | 1 
     12345     | prod02 | abc  | 2  | 2 
     12345     | prod03 | abc  | 2  | 3 
     12312     | prod04 | abc  | 2  | 4 
     12345     | prod03 | abc  | 2  | 3 
     88888     | prod05 | abc  | 2  | 5 
     99999     | prod03 | abc  | 2  | 3 
     99999     | prod05 | abc  | 2  | 5 
     12345     | prod03 | abc  | 2  | 3 
     """                                                                                                                  

df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text),sep=r"[\s\|]+",engine="python").sort_values("saleorder")                            

   saleorder product desc  id  quantity
0      10001  prod01  abc   2         1
3      12312  prod04  abc   2         4
1      12345  prod02  abc   2         2
2      12345  prod03  abc   2         3
4      12345  prod03  abc   2         3
8      12345  prod03  abc   2         3
5      88888  prod05  abc   2         5
6      99999  prod03  abc   2         3
7      99999  prod05  abc   2         5
```

At position 6 (not an index!) starts a new 'saleorder':

```
df1p= df.iloc[:6].pivot_table(index=['saleorder'],columns='product', values='quantity',aggfunc=sum)
df2p= df.iloc[6:].pivot_table(index=['saleorder'],columns='product', values='quantity',aggfunc=sum)

dfrslt= pd.concat([df1p,df2p],sort=False)                                                                                    

           prod01  prod02  prod03  prod04  prod05
saleorder                                        
10001         1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
12312         NaN     NaN     NaN     4.0     NaN
12345         NaN     2.0     9.0     NaN     NaN
88888         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     5.0
99999         NaN     NaN     3.0     NaN     5.0
```